# Linq to SQL Referential Integrity without database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm coding an app that uses an existing database, that database has some tables **I cannot modify at all**, I can nevertheless add new tables.
So, let's say I have an old table, Cities, to which I can read, create, update and delete but I cannot modify the schema.
I then add a new table, Clients, which has a foreign key to Cities, but I cannot add a relation on the database server (SQL SERVER 2008) as it also modifies the Cities table, adding a relation.
So I thought maybe if I add them both to my linq-to-sql context, and add the relation there, linq-to-sql would be clever enough to check for referential integrity for me, even though the relation is not established on the database, it's on the context.

I created a new project to try that out, I added two simple tables without a relation, then added the relation on the linq-to-sql designer, and tried to force an exception on referential integrity, but looks like it's not working.

```
DBContextDataContext db = new DBContextDataContext();

City l = new City();
l.name= "Buenos Aires";
db.Cities.InsertOnSubmit(l);

Client c = new Client();
c.name = "Mike";
c.City = l;
db.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(c);

db.SubmitChanges(); // This works

db.Cities.DeleteOnSubmit(l); 
db.SubmitChanges(); // This shouldn't work, but it works
```

Any idea if it's possible to force the referential integrity? Or adding the relation on the DB is the only way?

Comment: If you can add new tables, you can also add triggers. That's an awful way to manage referential integrity, but it will work...

Comment: I can add. Maybe that's a solution... I need to force those errors, as I inherited the system, and now I need to mantain it, but it barely checks for referential integrity, and allows the user to delete anything she wants... I just want to make sure it wont break the database integrity.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus You would need a trigger on the referenced table, Cities, to check that no Clients exist upon delete of that city. His premise is that he cannot modify the Cities schema.

Comment: You need to "maintain the system", so you can modify it, but you cannot modify the database? Does that mean that the database does not "belong to" the system? In other words, other systems are also modifying the data? In that case, nothing you do on the client would stop those other systems to alter data (e.g. delete a city). If you own the system, including the database, add the foreign key relationship.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten you're right. I think... But that's not that clear : how would a FK pointing on another schema "alter" that schema ? It could cause changes to other apps pointing to this schema ("why the hell can't I delete that city"), sure, but nothing to do with DB, no ? If rights are ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the SubmitChanges method on the DataContex, and verify the changes made.

```
    public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        bool everythingIsOK = true;

        var changes = GetChangeSet();
        var inserts = changes.Inserts;
        var deletes = changes.Deletes;
        var updates = changes.Updates;

        //verify everything is valid
        //...

        //if you need to, you can get the original state of the updated objects like this:
        foreach(object x in updates) {
            var original = this.GetTable(x.GetType()).GetOriginalEntityState(x);
            //verify the change doesn't break anything
            //...
        }

        if(everythingIsOK){ base.SubmitChanges(failureMode); }
    }
```

But feels painful. Are you absolutely sure, that you can't talk to the DBA to make the required changes? You can (i guess you are allowed to too) add a table, but can't add a foreign key, so the database may contain invalid data?

Also, if you have to verify changes this way, that means you have to make more queries to the db to verify all keys, etc is valid.

### Or this IS definitely a hack:

- Script the db schema for yourself
- Recreate the db on your machine, or wherever you want to
- Add the new tables, and add foreign keys to the db
- Generate the linq schema from your local modified db
- Change the connection string to the real one

And very fragile: if anything changes in the original db, you have to change it in your "dummy" db...

So still, try to reason with your boss, the DBA, or who made this decision, because you can't prevent a delete by someone else in the referenced table.

Comment: The problem is that the old database is the database of another 5 years old super tested and still on development HUGE visual basic 6 program. I'm writing an extension to that program, which is custom to the client's needs.

Comment: @gosukiwi without a real foreign key, you can only verify your own changes, but if someone from the other app deletes a city, your data is broken, and other users don't even notice it. You just can't do anything about it.

Comment: @gosukiwi So what? Is it a requirement that the VB6 monster can delete cities, thereby breaking your code? In fact, if it's still on development, talk to those developers and explain them that there code for deleting cities must be prepared to receive an error from the database.

Comment: Oh, and while you're talking to them, mention that VB6 hasn't been supported as a development platform by Microsoft for years...

Comment: I'm kind of new here, and they know that, but it's what was used at that time, I think it might be even older than 5 years, OOP was so new they didn't bother to use it back when it started I think, and it's one of the most successful programs at the company. There is a plan to go on the cloud though, with ASP.NET MVC.

I guess I'll have to check manually, and hope for the best, and very good testers.

Comment: @gosukiwi Couldn't the HUGE program you're extending be nice enough to raise an event (for you, or to have it, for your client) when a city is deleted ? Otherway, I don't see nothing but "batch" checks...

Comment: @gosukiwi Or another question : if you can add tables (even in another schema) : does the client have it's own database (then a FK wouldn't be a problem), or do all client of the HUGE app point on the same db ?